# Get value of input type text from innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
console.log(cleValTab.children[0].children[0].children[0].innerHTML);
```

which outputs

```
<input type="text" value="XXXX" class="table-textbox" size="50">
```

in cosole.

Now I need to extract the value and I tried adding `.value` but I got `undefined`.

Adding an `id` is not an option, since I'm looping through several text boxes.

Comment: Expand your script and use intermittent variables to assign to each element of your structure, you can't see from the one liner where the problem is.  Then check is variable for type and content before use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a **string** not a DOM. You can't read attributes from it without converting it back to a DOM.

So don't use `innerHTML` in the first place. Get the DOM node and read its attribute value.

```
console.log(cleValTab.children[0].children[0].children[0].querySelector("input").getAttribute("value"))
```

(Use the `value` property instead of `getAttribute` if you want the *current* value instead of the attribute value. Since you were trying to read from `innerHTML` I assume you want the attribute value).

Comment: @SPlatten — That's irrelevent to the problem at hand, and assumes that the HTML the code is running on is not robustly constructed.